# How do I create a vector that the user can keep adding values to between menu changes?

Tags: c++, vector, menu

Our homework assignment is to create a a menu where the user has the following options:

1. Add a planet
2. Delete planet
3. Find planet (by name)
4. List all planets
5. Sort (alphabetical order)
6. Quit

The requirements are that the planets must be stored as a class with name, diameter, mass as private members and the methods of the class being the density, surface area, and gravity. However I realized that I will need to use a vector to dynamically keep adding the planets as the user keeps entering them. How would I go about creating such a vector? And because I have to specifically use classes, where would the code for creating the vector go? Would it be at the beginning of `int main()` with a function inside to access the values (name, diameter, mass) entered by the user?

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class planet
{
    private:
        string n;
        double d, m;
    public:
        void Density (double d, double m)
        {
            double Den = m/((4.0/3.0)*M_PI*pow((d/2.0), 3.0));
            cout<<"Density: "<<Den<<endl;
        }
        void SurfaceArea(double d)
        {
            double S = 4.0*M_PI*pow((d/2.0), 2.0);
            cout<<"Surface Area: "<<S<<endl;
        }   
        void Name (string n)
        {
            string N = n;
            cout<<"Name: "<<N<<endl;
        }
        void Gravity (double G, double m, double d)
        {
            double F = G*m/pow((d/2.0), 2.0);
            cout<<"Force of gravity: "<<F<<endl;
        }

};

int main()
{
    const double G=6.67384e-11;
    int c=0;
    string n;
    double d=0.0, m=0.0, Den=0.0, S=0.0;

    do 
    {
        cout<<"1. Add a planet\n";
        cout<<"2. Delete planet\n";
        cout<<"3. Find planet (by name)\n";
        cout<<"4. List all planets\n";
        cout<<"5. Sort (alphabetical order)\n";
        cout<<"6. Quit\n";
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Please select an option from the menu above."<<endl;
        cin>>c;

        if(c==1)
        {
            planet red;

            cout<<"Enter the planet's name: ";
            cin>>n;
            cout<<"Enter the planet's diameter: ";
            cin>>d;
            cout<<"Enter the planet's mass: ";
            cin>>m;

            red.Name(n);
            red.Density(d, m);
            red.SurfaceArea(d/2.0);
            red.Gravity(G, m, d);



        }
        else if (c==4)
        {
            cout<<N<<endl;
            cout<<Den<<endl;
            cout<<S<<endl;
            cout<<F<<endl;
        }


    } while (c!=6);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

If I need to clarify more please let me know nicely :)

Thanks!

Comment: `Would it be at the beginning of int main() with a function inside to access the values (name, diameter, mass) entered by the user?`  Why not try and see if it works?

Comment: I do that a lot, it's a terrible habit I've developed. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a vector like this `vector<planet> p` to create a vector that can store your class `planet`. You'd want to create this vector at the start of the program so that it is ready to get filled as soon as users start entering data.

To add a planet, just `push_back` the planet.  To delete, use the vector's `erase` function.

To find a planet in your vector, just iterate through your vector with a `for` loop and see if `p.at(i).n == planet_to_find` .

To print all the planets, like the find loop, iterate through your planets and `cout << p.at(i).n`.

To sort, you can use the `std` `sort` function to sort alphabetically. [Details on sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

I hope this helps :)

Comment: If I wanted to not only add the planet name but also some data with it (e.g. Pluto, diameter=5, mass=20), how could I ensure that the diameter and mass also get deleted if I delete by planet name?

Comment: If you'd like to test it, you can iterate through your vector and check `p.at(i).d` or `p.at(i).m` to see if they still exist after you call `erase`.

Comment: I believe you are having trouble with how `erase` works. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) for details.
To erase a planet from you vector, do `p.erase(p.begin(), p.begin() + i)`.  This will delete the planet (with its name, diameter, mass). Please up vote and check this answer if it helps or answered your question.

Comment: @masfo001 `p.erase(p.begin(), p.begin() + i)` is going to wipe out everything from the beginning of the vector to the ith element. Probably not what you meant to suggest. `p.erase(p.begin() + i)`

Comment: @heyheythere you have all of the planet data bundled up in a class. If you remove an object based on the class then all of the object's class data goes with it. Where goeth the object, goeth the data.

Comment: Wow strangely enough the data was successfully deleted. I'm not really sure how that worked...

Comment: As @user4581301 said, if you delete the class object, you delete all of its data with it. And yes, its `p.erase(p.begin() + i)`

Comment: @heyheythere `Wow strangely enough the data was successfully deleted.`  Your `planet` doesn't store any data.  Where do you set `d`, `m`, and `n` in your `planet` object?  Nowhere.

Comment: In choice #1 (adding a planet) I pass `n, d, m` to the object via `red.Name(n); red.Density(d, m); red.SurfaceArea(d/2.0); red.Gravity(G, m, d);` I thought this was the same thing. What do you mean by "setting them" in my planet object?

Comment: @heyheythere, hate to be a downer, but it's time for you to pick up the textbook, read it, and do the sample problems. We can't explain what's going wrong in, for example, the planet::Name method without covering  fundamentals that are already explained to death elsewhere and quite possibly better than we can do here in this format.